# Is it legal to add the same action listener to a JComboBox and JButton

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Good Morning, i tried to add the same action listener for both a JComboBox and JButton but at runtime a `ClassCastException` occurs as follows `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton` , have added the listener to both of them as follows:

```
jComboBox1.addActionListener(this);
jButton1.addActionListener(this);
```

and the actionPerformed method is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    JButton button=(JButton)e.getSource();
    JComboBox sCombo=(JComboBox)e.getSource();

    if(sCombo.equals(jComboBox1))
        listModel.addElement(sCombo.getSelectedItem());
    else
        listModel2.addElement(sCombo.getSelectedItem());

    if(button.equals(jButton1))
        System.out.println("Button1 is pressed");
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to format code.   To format it, select the code sample and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form.  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are actually implementing an `ActionListener`, you *could* use `instanceof` here:

```
Object sourceObject = e.getSource();
if (sourceObject instanceof JButton) {
   JButton button=(JButton)sourceObject;
   ...
} else if (sourceObject instanceof JComboBox) {
   JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)sourceObject;
   ...
}
```

but its better practice to assign a separate listener to each control, especially here given the very differing tasks that the each control is performing.

Comment: Agreeing and expanding: It would be appropriate to use an `instanceof` if you were doing in some sense the *same thing* with the two types of controls with a slight variation (e.g. to get a selected-item in some sense and then do a common thing with it), but since the code is completely different in the two cases, there is no good reason to use the same `ActionListener`. Given Java's inner classes and anonymous inner classes, it's so simple to create a separate listener for each case that you really should do that.

Comment: Yes, I agree, separate listeners are a better fit here and remove the need for component type checking.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal but do this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        JButton button=(JButton)e.getSource();
        System.out.println("Button1 is pressed");
    } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
        /* watever you doing with combobox */
    }
}
```